# check for logout status in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have written below query to retrieve the values,

```
select * from abc where status in ('login,'logout');
```

| Status | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Login | 2021-08-29 10:00:00 |
| Logout | 2021-08-29 10:30:00 |
| Login | 2021-08-29 11:00:00 |

In the table above, I have to check if the latest logout status is empty or present. But logout is not done yet.

I want to use IF condition to check if logout status is empty or present and it should use only the latest values. For example, the above query retrieves all values, but I want only the latest value ,that is

Login is at 2021-08-29 11:00:00 , but logout is not done yet.

I want only last record as output. Suppose if logout has been done,

| Status | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Login | 2021-08-29 10:00:00 |
| Logout | 2021-08-29 10:30:00 |
| Login | 2021-08-29 11:00:00 |
| Logout | 2021-08-29 11:30:00 |

Then I should get,

| Status | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Login | 2021-08-29 11:00:00 |
| Logout | 2021-08-29 11:30:00 |

as output

Comment: What if there is no logout, Then how you want to show your output.

Comment: Then logout will be null

Answer (score 0):

The following approach uses window functions to determine the last login time and the logout time after the last login time

```sql
SELECT
   status, time
FROM (
   select 
        status,time ,
        CASE
            WHEN status='Login' AND 
                 (time = MAX(time) OVER (PARTITION BY status)) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END as is_last_login,
        CASE
            WHEN status='Logout' AND 
                 (time > MAX(CASE WHEN status='Login' THEN time END) OVER ()) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END as is_logout_after_last_login
    from 
        abc 
    where 
        status in ('Login','Logout')
)  t
WHERE
    t.is_last_login=1 OR t.is_logout_after_last_login=1;
```

or

```sql
WITH last_login_time AS (
    select max(time) last_login from abc where status='Login'
)
select
    status,
    time
from
    abc
where
    (
        status='Login' AND time = (select last_login from last_login_time)
    ) OR
    (
        status='Logout' AND time > (select last_login from last_login_time)
    )
```

[Working Demo Db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7c98a93a0bc37eba470fd30ec8161ebe)

#### Edit 1

Left joining on a temporary table as shown in the example query below will also provide a null result for Logout if there is no logout entry as yet

```sql
WITH last_login_time AS (
    select max(time) last_login from abc where status='Login'
),
login_logout_times AS (
    select
        status,
        time
    from
        abc
    where
    (
        status='Login' AND time = (select last_login from last_login_time)
    ) OR
    (
        status='Logout' AND time > (select last_login from last_login_time)
    ) 
)
select
    d.status,
    l.time 
from (
    select 'Login' as status from dual
    union all
    select 'Logout' as status from dual
) d
left join login_logout_times l on l.status=d.status
```

[Working Demo Db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f8067f5f01b75d54c2685cb2445a904f)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the correct sequence is maintained by the logging application (`Login` before `Logout` and no consecutive duplicates of the same status), then you need to select the last two statuses and decide, whether to show the time of `Logout` (if it is the last), or not (if it is followed by `Login` status).

> ```
> insert into t(status, time)
> select 'Login', timestamp '2021-08-29 10:00:00' from dual union all
> select 'Logout', timestamp '2021-08-29 10:30:00' from dual union all
> select 'Login', timestamp '2021-08-29 11:00:00' from dual
> ```

> ```
> create view v_test as
> with last_ as (
>   select t.*
>     , row_number() over(partition by status order by time desc) as rn
>     /*There should be nothing after last logout*/
>     , lead(status) over(order by time) as next_status
>   from t
>   where status in ('Login', 'Logout')
> )
> select
>   status
>   /*
>     Show the time of the last status (regardless of its type),
>     And the time of the Login status if it's followed by Logout.
>   */
>   , decode(next_status, 'Logout', time, null, time) as time
> from last_
> where rn = 1
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from v_test
> ```
>
> ```
> STATUS | TIME               
> :----- | :------------------
> Login  | 2021-08-29 11:00:00
> Logout | null
> ```

> ```
> insert into t(status, time)
> values('Logout', timestamp '2021-08-29 11:30:00')
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from v_test
> ```
>
> ```
> STATUS | TIME               
> :----- | :------------------
> Login  | 2021-08-29 11:00:00
> Logout | 2021-08-29 11:30:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c47a7e0d7fad843b174088c62c21780)*